# PHP Function modifications (copy folder - set its permissions)

Tags: php, filesystems

I am using this function:

```
function rcopy($src, $dst) {
  if (file_exists($dst)) rrmdir($dst);
  if (is_dir($src)) {
    mkdir($dst);
    $files = scandir($src);
    foreach ($files as $file)
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") rcopy("$src/$file", "$dst/$file"); 
  }
  else if (file_exists($src)) copy($src, $dst);
}

rcopy("$source_folder", "$target_folder");
```

It works great but I need a way to set the permissions to the $target_folder.

Another got any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`chmod()`](http://php.net/chmod) function to the target_folder.